# Ex hijacked my Facebook account

Tags: facebook, account-management, security

A disgruntled ex hijacked my Facebook account, which I abandoned years ago, and posted photos of me in compromised circumstances. I can no longer gain access to the account, and I don't remember the email address associated with it.

I've looked, and none of the categories on the FB help pages apply to my situation. I need the account, or at least the photos, deleted. Is there anything I can do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using forgot password by using the password recovery process through email you can try gaining access but other wise there is no possibility to gain the access by of hijacked accounts in facebook

Answer (score 0):

Go to your hijacked account. Block it. When you'll try blocking it, Facebook will provide you with a few options. There is one which says *It's my old account* or something like this. You can get the account taken down by following the walk-through from there. I hope it helps.